# Find regular expression matching condition

Tags: linux, bash

I have a set of files including a date in their name: 
`MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151229.SUB.nc
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151230.SUB.nc
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151231.SUB.nc`

I want to select the files matching a condition on this date. In this example: date > 20151230

I tried things like:
`find . -regex ".*.SUB.nc" | cut -d "." -f 4 | while read a; do if [ $a -ge 20151201 ]; then echo $a; fi; done`
BUT:
1) This is returning only a part of the filename, whereas I would like to return the entire filename. 
2) There may be a more elegant way than using while read/do

thanks in advance!

Comment: replace echo $a  to ls *$a*. Your command will work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rearranging your code becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find . -regex ".*.SUB.nc" \                                              
    | rev | cut -d '.' -f 3 | rev \                                                 
    | while read a; do                                                   
          if [ $a -ge 20151201 ]; then                                   
              echo $a                                                  
          fi                                                            
      done
```

`rev | cut -d '.' -f 3 | rev` is used because

1. if you give absolute path or
2. the subdirectories have `.` in them

then it won't be the `4th` field, but it will always be the `3rd` last field.

This will give the output:

```
20151231                                                                 
20151229                                                                 
20151230
```

To show the complete file names change `echo $a` with `ls *$a*`. Output:

```
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151231.SUB.nc                               
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151229.SUB.nc                               
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151230.SUB.nc
```

I tested this script with file names whose dates are less than `20151201`. For example `MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151200.SUB.nc`. The results are consistent.

Perhaps a more efficient way to accomplish your task is using a grep regex like:

```
find . -regex ".*.SUB.nc" | grep -E "201512(0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])|201[6-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

Comment: If some file are present in sub directories it won't work.

Comment: `-r` is for `reverse` not for `recursively`.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.

Comment: with grep regex method you have to hardcode the date whereas I want to include it as a parameter (which I didn't mention). First method works fine, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This will work just fine.

```
find . -regex ".*.SUB.nc" | rev | cut -d '.' -f 3 | rev | while read a; do if [ $a -ge 20151201 ]; then echo `ls -R | grep $a` ;fi ;done
```

`rev | cut -d '.' -f 3 | rev` is used because

1. if you give absolute path or
2. the subdirectories have `.` in them

then it won't be the `4th` field now, but it will always be the `3rd` last field always.

`ls -R | grep $a` so that you can recursively find out the name of the file.

Assume is the files and file structure is :

```
[root@localhost temp]# ls -lrt -R
.:
total 8
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Apr 25 16:15 MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151231.SUB.nc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Apr 25 16:15 MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151230.SUB.nc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Apr 25 16:15 MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151229.SUB.nc
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr 25 16:32 temp.3
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Apr 25 17:13 temp2

./temp.3:
total 0

./temp2:
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Apr 25 16:27 MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151111.SUB.nc
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    0 Apr 25 16:27 MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151222.SUB.nc
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr 25 17:13 temp21

./temp2/temp21:
total 0
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Apr 25 17:13 MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151333.SUB.nc
```

Running above command gives :

```
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151229.SUB.nc
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151231.SUB.nc
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151230.SUB.nc
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151333.SUB.nc
MERRA2_400.tavg1_2d_slv_Nx.20151222.SUB.nc
```